# Using Nav Drawer Settings in different Activity

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

So I am creating an app that I want the user to be able to decide if they want to use WiFi or 4G to fetch the data after logging in (I will make another question about implementing the decision later, unless anyone wants to add that here too). So currently I have a MainActivity.java that will be handling the logging in (which I have yet to implement) and I have a NavDrawerActivity.java for the Navigation Drawer. Now obviously once I do the "log in" it goes to the Nav Drawer. However, I want the user to be able to choose whether or not to use Wifi or Data before logging in as well as being able to choose once they log in. So I guess this is a two part question, how would you implement this as well as, is it a good idea to put that in the login screen? Or should I just default it to always use wifi unless they change it and if I detect WiFi isn't enabled, have them enable it?

MainActivity.java code

```
package com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;


import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.json.JSONTokener;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText emailText;
    TextView responseView;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    static final String API_KEY = "USE_YOUR_OWN_API_KEY";
    static final String API_URL = "https://api.fullcontact.com/v2/person.json?";
    static final String ClientId= "";
    static final String ClientSecret = "";



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        responseView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.responseView);
        emailText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailText);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        final Context context = this;
        Button queryButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.queryButton);
        queryButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new RetrieveFeedTask().execute();

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, NavDrawerActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }


    class RetrieveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        private Exception exception;

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            responseView.setText("");
        }

        protected String doInBackground(Void... urls) {
            String email = emailText.getText().toString();
            // Do some validation here

            try {
                URL url = new URL(API_URL + "email=" + email + "&apiKey=" + API_KEY);
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                try {
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;
                    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
                    }
                    bufferedReader.close();
                    return stringBuilder.toString();
                }
                finally{
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage(), e);
                return null;
            }
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String response) {
            if(response == null) {
                response = "THERE WAS AN ERROR";
            }
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Log.i("INFO", response);
            responseView.setText(response);
            // TODO: check this.exception
            // TODO: do something with the feed

//            try {
//                JSONObject object = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(response).nextValue();
//                String requestID = object.getString("requestId");
//                int likelihood = object.getInt("likelihood");
//                JSONArray photos = object.getJSONArray("photos");
//                .
//                .
//                .
//                .
//            } catch (JSONException e) {
//                e.printStackTrace();
//            }
        }
    }
}
```

NavDrawerActivity.java code

```
package com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi;

import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;




public class NavDrawerActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_nav_drawer);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);

            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    //Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    //.setAction("Action", null).show();
                    Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
                    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)));
                }
            });


        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.nav_drawer, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        FragmentManager fragmentSettingsManager = getFragmentManager();
        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            fragmentSettingsManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new SettingsFragment()).commit();
            setTitle(R.string.action_settings);
            FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
            fab.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        if (id == R.id.nav_first_layout) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new FirstFragment()).commit();
            setTitle(R.string.speed_graph);
            FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
            fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_second_layout) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new SecondFragment()).commit();
            setTitle(R.string.drive_player);
            FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
            fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_third_layout) {
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new ThirdFragment()).commit();
            setTitle(R.string.google_maps);
            FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
            fab.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {
            Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
            sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Go Check Out All Driving Data in the Play Store!");
            sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)));
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Let me know if there is anything else you guys need and thank you guys for all the help :)

Here is the WifivsDataDialog code

```
    package com.example.jamessingleton.chffrapi;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;

/**
 * Created by James Singleton on 8/9/2016.
 */

public class WifivsDataDialog extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_box)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.WiFi, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // FIRE ZE MISSILES!
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.Cell_Data, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        // User cancelled the dialog
                    }
                });
        // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you would like to achieve.

Is it mandatory to fetch the data? What if the user has both Wi-Fi and mobile network disabled on the device? What if they choose to use Wi-Fi, but have only mobile network enabled on the device?

I would create a `Dialog` at the start of the app that explains this stuff and let the user choose if they would like to allow fetching data on mobile network, or Wi-Fi only, with a *"Do not show this dialog again"* `CheckBox`.

If the user chooses with the `CheckBox` checked, then that will be the default behaviour on further launches (and can be changed in the Preferences/Settings).

You could show the `Dialog` from the `onCreate()` of your login `Activity`.

For example:

*connection_dialog.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Would you like to allow fetching data on mobile network?"/>

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Yes"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="No, allow Wi-Fi only"/>
    </RadioGroup>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:text="OK"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

*ConnectionDialogFragment.java*:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class ConnectionDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    public ConnectionDialogFragment() {
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.connection_dialog, container, false);

        // set up your View here

        return view;
    }
}
```

And in your `Activity`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_activity_layout);

    // ...

    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    if(prefs.getBoolean("show_dialog", true)) {
        showDialog();
    }
}

private void showDialog() {
    ConnectionDialogFragment dialog = new ConnectionDialogFragment();
    dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "connection_dialog");
}
```

Check out the developer's guide on [Dialogs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html).

When the user has chosen whether they want to use Wi-Fi only, or allow mobile network also, you could check the available connection with something like this:

```
// this method will return either
// ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE
// or
// ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI
// or -1 (if no connection is available)
private int checkAvailableConnectionType() {
    ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    int type = activeNetwork.getType();
    if(activeNetwork.isConnected() && (type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE ||
            type == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)) {
        return type;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

And do your stuff according to the user's choice and the currently active connection (advise the user to turn on Wi-Fi, for example).